# How to force to use library support 26 with Loaders

Tags: android, loader, legacy-code

I am upgrading to API 28 from API 26 and I am having problems with LoaderManagers because it is returning null.

Error:

```
Object returned from onCreateLoader must not be null
```

This is my code with API 26 and it was working fine:

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID_REQUESTS, null, this);
```

I can not change to Livedata or Viewmodel because it is a legacy code, so I am looking for a solution without too much pain. I was thinking to force to use support library v4 26.1.0, almost in loaders imports or something like that.

Any suggestion? Remember, change to livedata or viewmodel is not a possibility in short terms.

Comment: Well, how are you returning null from `onCreateLoader()`? That's in your code somewhere. It doesn't have a default return value, or anything.

Comment: agreed, you need to make sure onCreateLoader() is not returning null. The deprecated getSupportLoaderManager() will still work if you fix this. If you share your onCreateLoader code then this can be fixed